# Is there a downside to using named, rather than numbered, capture groups in Java?

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

I tend to prefer named capture groups when I use regular expressions. I find that they eliminate a lot of confusion, so that rather than needing to figure out the number of groups preceding your group, you just give a group its own label and can access it without further thought. Still, I see most Regex examples on this site, even in new answers using numbered capture groups, and I'm not sure if they know something I don't, or if I know something they don't. My question is, are there any downsides to using named, rather than numbered, groups (eg. performance, etc.)?

Comment: A part of it may be because `Matcher` didn't have a `group(String)` method until java 7 (I believe - certainly not in java 5); so for backwards compatibility people use numbered groups.  I suppose there's the additional performance hit of the regex parser having to get your name, and the `String` construction (possibly) when invoking the `group` method.  But I doubt those are of significant concern.